# Android Read/Write large file when activity is destoyed

Tags: android, file, kotlin

When the activity or fragment is destroyed I want to write a large 1-10MB file. Since I want to store the file when the user closes the application I have to do that inside the **onPause()** method. I use **[DataOutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataOutputStream)** because it has methods for writing different types: Integer, Float, ByteArray and many more.

Lets say I need to write a large file and it take 2-3 seconds. The code in method **onPause()** is executed on the main thread. Lets say I freeze the thread for 6s to simulate the thread doing work, using **Thread.sleep(6000)**. If the user try to return to the application the application is not responding for those 6 seconds, because all the work is done in the main thread.

If I start a AsyncTask that run the task on separate thread and do the writing of the file there, the problem with the freezing UI is solved. But as far as I know if the task takes 6s, and the application is destroyed before the thread has finished working, there is a big problem with memory leaks!

So my question is how to write a big file, on separate thread when the user is about to close the application and prevent memory leaks???
Below is example code of writing everything on the main thread:

```
override fun onStop() {
    // code is run in the main thread
    saveFile(context!!, "test", "testFile.txt")
}

fun saveFile(context: Context, fileDirectory: String, fileName: String) {

        // path to /data/data/yourAppName/app_data/imageDir
        val directory: File = context.getDir(fileDirectory, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        val file = File(directory, fileName)
        val fileOutputStream: FileOutputStream
        try {

            fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            val dataOutputStream = DataOutputStream(fileOutputStream)

            dataOutputStream.writeInt(11)                       // write integer
            dataOutputStream.writeFloat(1.8f)                   // write float
            dataOutputStream.write(byteArrayOf(1, 33, 124, 41)) // write byte array

            dataOutputStream.flush()
            dataOutputStream.close()
            fileOutputStream.flush()
            fileOutputStream.close()

        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Since I need the context to generate the File and if the activity is destroyed before the thread has finished working that would lead to memory leaks. If I wrap the context in WeakReference does that protect it from memory leaks?? And will the thread finish its work even if the activity/fragment is destroyed??

Below is example of using AsyncTask, and wrap the context in WeakReference!

```
class SaveFile(context: Context, var fileDirectory: String, var fileName: String) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Int>() {

            private var contextWrapper: WeakReference<ContextWrapper>

            init {
                val contextWrapper = ContextWrapper(context)
                this.contextWrapper = WeakReference(contextWrapper)
            }

            override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): Int {
                val directory: File = contextWrapper.get()!!.getDir(fileDirectory, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

                val file = File(directory, fileName)
                val fileOutputStream: FileOutputStream
                try {

                    fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                    val dataOutputStream = DataOutputStream(fileOutputStream)

                    dataOutputStream.writeInt(11)                     // write integer
                    dataOutputStream.writeFloat(1.8f)                 // write float
                    dataOutputStream.write(byteArrayOf(1, 33, 124, 41)) // write byte array

                    dataOutputStream.flush()
                    dataOutputStream.close()
                    fileOutputStream.flush()
                    fileOutputStream.close()

                } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                
                return 0
            } 
        }
```

Comment: This is the place where you use services. Start a service on `onPause` or `onDestroy`.

Comment: So I should use IntentService that displays a message for the user that his work is being saved right now.

Comment: A notification would probably be better.

Comment: Use a Thread instead of an AsyncTask. But why do some memory leaks bother you?

Comment: @blackapps a memory leak should ALWAYS be treated as a serious issue.

Comment: Thanks I ended up using 'Foreground services', with separate thread it works well. It save the data even if the activity/fragment is destroyed and as soon as the job got finished I kill the thread and the service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `applicationContext` (which you can get from any `Context`) if you want to make sure you're not holding onto an `Activity` or whatever. But holding onto an `Activity` for a few extra seconds isn't really a leak - there's no guarantee you'd even get a garbage collection event in that timespan anyway! It's long-lived references you need to be careful of.

Your `WeakReference` idea does prevent memory leaks by releasing the `Context` when nothing else is holding it - the problem is you're treating it as though it always returns the context, by saying

```
contextWrapper.get()!!
```

In the event your weak reference does its job and releases the context, this call returns **null**, and your non-null assertion (`!!`) fails and crashes your app. So you're swapping your potential memory usage issue for a much bigger one!

If you're ever doing this kind of thing, you need to handle the situation where the object with the weak reference has been garbage collected - that's what you're doing with the weak reference, making it so you can't guarantee you'll have access to it.

So you want something like this instead

```
val directory: File? = contextWrapper.get()?.getDir(fileDirectory, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
if (directory == null) return
...
```

it's up to you how you handle the "no context" path, here I'm just giving up on the file stuff. If that's not an option, and you *need* that `Context` so you can do something important, then you can't just hold a weak reference to one.

I know you've already worked something out with services, but this is an important thing to know!

Comment: Thank you! Yea you are absolutely right I totally forget that there is probability for the context to be null. I have problems with the service now, you can ckeck my latest question in case you had the same problem in the past and you manage to fix it.

Comment: Honestly, never use ``!!`` - the context **can** be null and that's why it's a nullable ``Context?`` type, and the null-safety system and linter will warn you you need to handle it. Using ``!!`` is breaking that and telling the system you know better - and in some rare cases you will, but as a rule you should avoid using it at all!